# How much disk space do I need for Windows 7/8 and XBox game development with XNA?

Tags: windows-7

I currently own a 15" MacBook Pro, and want to get it set up for doing Windows and XBox game development using XNA.

I will be installing the following on the windows machine:

1. Windows 7 64 bit
2. Visual Studio 2010
3. XNA
4. Microsoft Kinect SDK

Assuming that I use this partition for nothing but windows development, what would be a good size for the Windows partition, bearing in mind that I would likely be upgrading to Windows 8 in the semi-near future? My hard drive is 500 GB, and I am currently using ~300 GB on the Mac side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the amount of content your games will use, but I can say that I have more than enough disk space available and I only have a 120GB SSD drive in my laptop.

If it's for mostly coding I don't think you would need more than 60-80GB, but I would recommend 100GB at least.

Comment: I was thinking somewhere around 90-100 as well. Thanks!

Comment: Yea, that sounds like a good number. Worst case you can always add another partition, or connect a USB disk.